# No sound from remote notification in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am using `GCM` to send apple push notification to my ios app, notifications working well but with no sound.
How can I fix this issue please?
This is my code below :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Preloads keyboard so there's no lag on initial keyboard appearance.
    let lagFreeField:UITextField = UITextField();

    self.window?.addSubview(lagFreeField);
    lagFreeField.becomeFirstResponder();
    lagFreeField.resignFirstResponder();
    lagFreeField.removeFromSuperview();

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    var configureError:NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
    gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound.union(UIUserNotificationType.Alert), categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    let gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
    gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self
    GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with Google Cloud Messaging. They only support the "default" value for the sound tag. So whenever I changed it to anything but that the GCM server does not send the sound tag at all.
[cloud-messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)
[image]